# How can Jack Harding also control the Mayor?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, 3-ninjas-knuckle-up

In the 1995 Action Film "3 Ninjas Knuckle up", the Main Villain owns the Town which means that he controls the Police but I don't quite understand how he can also control the Mayor? Doesn't a Mayor have full control over a Town or City?

Comment: I've not seen the movie (and probably never will) - but while a Mayor has a legal role and some power in a town, that doesn't make them all powerful or unable to be blackmailed, or above being bribed. A corrupt public official like a Mayor is a common trope in movies.